# Can kubernetes resource request/limit definition slow down pods?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I am running 3 deployments of the same app on a kubernetes cluster. I recently got around to setting resource requests and limits for one of the deployments.

```
resources:
    limits:
        cpu: 350m
        memory: 225Mi
    requests:
        cpu: 250m
        memory: 150Mi
```

After setting these, the affected pods have a much higher computation time compared to the **2 unchanged deployments**, which does not make sense regarding kubernetes documentation as I understand it.

Running `kubectl top pods` allows me to confirm my pods are running at or below requested resources. When visualizing computation time (Prometheus+Grafana), it is clear one of the deployments is significantly slower:

[image]

*Two deployments at ~ 60ms and one at ~ 120ms*

As this is the only change I have made, I don't understand why there should be any performance degradation. Am I missing something?

---

## Edit

Removing the cpu `limit` but keeping the `request` brings pod performance back to what it's supposed to be. Keeping in mind that these pods are running at cpu request level (around 250mCPU) which is 100mCPU below the limit.

[image]

*Additional information: these pods are running a NodeJS app.*

Comment: To throw out a possibility, you could be running a Java-based process that's aware of the Kubernetes memory limits and in turn limits its own heap size; that causes it to do more garbage collection and generally run slower.  You'll probably need to do some more detailed investigation to actually understand this.

Comment: @DavidMaze I'm running NodeJS apps, I'll have a look into the GC process, thanks for the hint

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kubernetes CPU limits might not work as one would assume. I suggest to watch [this presentation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eBChCFD9hfs) starting at 13:38.

A solution to the negative effect of CPU limits in k8s might be to set a different CFS quota value. By default it's set to 100ms, a better value might be 5ms. There is also an [issue](http://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/51135) about this.

Comment: Thank you for the link to the presentation. Do you know how one would set CPU period in the new kubernetes versions ?

Comment: I believe you do this by setting the `--cpu-manager-policy=static` for the kubelet as described here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/cpu-management-policies. Did you manage to solve this?

Comment: There is also a whole presentation about it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UE7QX98-kO0

Answer (score 3):

Reading this link i understand that if a pod is successfully started, the container is guaranteed the amount of resources requested so scheduling is based on requests field in yaml and not the limit field but the pods and its containers will not be allowed to exceed the specified limit on yaml.

***Pods will be throttled if they exceed their limit. If limit is unspecified, then the pods can use excess CPU when available.***

Refer the link for complete read 
https://github.com/kubernetes/community/blob/master/contributors/design-proposals/node/resource-qos.md#compressible-resource-guarantees

Comment: That's a very interesting link, thanks! I find it surprising that this is translated as `A Container might or might not be allowed to exceed its CPU limit` in the "mainstream" [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-compute-resources-container/#how-pods-with-resource-limits-are-run).

Comment: _A Container might or might not be allowed to exceed its CPU limit for extended periods of time. However, it will not be killed for excessive CPU usage._ I believe the reading the last line _will not be killed_ translates to throttling of CPU to let it run instead of a kill.

Comment: May be this can be made more clear on official documentation .. refer below link on docs it does mention CPU throttling when limit is exceed. [CPU-limit](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/assign-cpu-resource/#specify-a-cpu-request-and-a-cpu-limit)

Comment: Yes, I see `The container’s CPU use is being throttled, because the container is attempting to use more CPU resources than its limit.` Thanks. This, unfortunately, does not explain why my pods would be throttled as they are running below or at `requestd` cpu.

Answer (score 0):

The pods which are not having any requests and limits might be using the node's resources with out any restriction. so it can be faster.

The pods which are having limits will be limited so they can be slow.

Please check resource consumption metrics of both deployments.

Comment: The 'unrestricted' pods have a *slightly* higher CPU usage (210 mCPU vs. 200 mCPU). But this is still below resource request. Also, can you point to a bit of documentation that says kubernetes would limit pod performance? I have never run across any mention of it.

Comment: And my cluster average CPU rarely goes over 60%, so there is still plenty of resources left.